# My function will always tell me that I got my question wrong. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, math, parseint, pi

I made a function that will quizzes you on Pi. For every digit you write correctly, you get half of a point. However, even if I just type '3', it'll say that I did it incorrectly. Please help.

```js
function pi() {
  var piWithoutDecimals = 31415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679;
  var yourAnswer = prompt("Pi Bonus! Half of a point for every digit of pi that you can write from memory!");
  var yourAnswerNum = parseInt(yourAnswer);
  var yourAnswerMultiplier = yourAnswerNum.toString().split(".");
  var yourAdjustedAnswer = yourAnswerNum*(10**parseInt(yourAnswerMultiplier));
  var yourAdjustedAnswerCount = yourAdjustedAnswer.toString().length;
  var yourSectionOfpiWithoutDecimals = piWithoutDecimals.toString().substring(0,parseInt(yourAdjustedAnswer-1));
  if(yourSectionOfpiWithoutDecimals==yourAnswerNum) {
    alert("Nice!! You listed "+yourAdjustedAnswerCount+" digits of Pi, and so you get "+Math.floor((yourAdjustedAnswerCount)/2)+" points!")
    points+=Math.floor((yourAdjustedAnswerCount)/2);
  } else { alert("Good try, but you got one or more digits incorrect.") }
}

pi()
```

Comment: You have a double multiplier on yourAdjustedAnswer: **, is that correct?

Comment: All modern browsers come with a debugger that allows you to step through code line-by-line and inspect values along the way. [Here's how you do it in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints).

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith `**`, in latest version of javascript, means `Math.pow`

Answer (score 0):

You might have a simple approach.

1. Define your pi in a string
2. Take user input
3. Check if your pi string starts with what user have input
4. Remove decimal point `.`, and count length to get number of correctly entered digits.
5. Display output of your quiz

```js
function pi() {
  const pi = "3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679";
  const yourAnswer = prompt("Pi Bonus! Half of a point for every digit of pi that you can write from memory!");
  if(pi.startsWith(yourAnswer)) {
    const yourAdjustedAnswerCount = yourAnswer.replace('.', '').length;
    alert(`Nice!! You listed ${yourAdjustedAnswerCount} digits of Pi, and so you get ${Math.floor(yourAdjustedAnswerCount / 2)} points!`)

  } else { 
    alert("Good try, but you got one or more digits incorrect.")
  }
}

pi()
```

Comment: Answers which explain the modifications made to code are downvoted less often than those which simply give the answer in code...

Comment: The question is why OP's code does not work. You should try to answer that.

Comment: Might be better to write the entirety of the answer, then post, rather than making people wait...

Comment: @FK82 It's sometimes better to approach differently than the OP does.

Comment: @HereticMonkey That's absolutely right. However, I have many times seen people answer with a simple code snippet faster than me and later edit it to better answer while I was trying to write best answer

Comment: Yeah, and if fewer people did that, it would be better, yes? See [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19533/194720).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Haha! FGITW problem. Awesome definition. Yes, I agree that it would better if fewer people did that. Thank you for taking your time to find the link to that meme!

Answer (score 0):

You first go wrong at this line:

```
var yourAnswerMultiplier = yourAnswerNum.toString().split(".");
```

If you log this value for e.g. the input `"314"`, you'll get the array `["314"]` (your probably wanted `.split("")`). Going from there, `yourAdjustedAnswer` will be Infinity (since 10 ** 314 is too large and simply overflows). This fails which is obviously not what you wanted.

As a suggestion, try to step through the execution for a simple example using the developer tools of your browser/IDE and watch closely if each step is according to your expectation.

@Orkhan Alikhanov's answer might also provide some hints.

```js
    function pi() {
      var piWithoutDecimals = 31415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679;
      var yourAnswer = prompt("Pi Bonus! Half of a point for every digit of pi that you can write from memory!");
      var yourAnswerNum = parseInt(yourAnswer);
      var yourAnswerMultiplier = yourAnswerNum.toString().split(".");
      var yourAdjustedAnswer = yourAnswerNum*(10**parseInt(yourAnswerMultiplier));
      console.log(yourAdjustedAnswer)
      var yourAdjustedAnswerCount = yourAdjustedAnswer.toString().length;
      var yourSectionOfpiWithoutDecimals = piWithoutDecimals.toString().substring(0,parseInt(yourAdjustedAnswer-1));
      if(yourSectionOfpiWithoutDecimals==yourAnswerNum) {
        alert("Nice!! You listed "+yourAdjustedAnswerCount+" digits of Pi, and so you get "+Math.floor((yourAdjustedAnswerCount)/2)+" points!")
        points+=Math.floor((yourAdjustedAnswerCount)/2);
      } else { alert("Good try, but you got one or more digits incorrect.") }
    }

    pi()
```